# How to show only USA and Canada in Shopping cart Summary ? - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

I'm trying to find a way to show only United States and Canada as options in my Shopping Cart>Summary>Estimate Shipping and Tax select field.

I did many changes in the backend, however, but all the other countries keep showing.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for this is in Store -> Configuration -> General and select your countries in "Allow Countries" However there is a bug that prevent it from working correctly.

[image]

To fix this issue take a look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7b1ac83b92228803884f04cb74505b776bef59cd.

[image]